# ...GatsbySanityImageFluid - Cannot read property 'fluid' of null

Tags: graphql, gatsby, sanity

I'm working with Sanity and Gatsby

I'm trying to map over an array of images to display them in an image gallery. My GraphQL query is working, I am able to display a single image but I receive the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fluid' of null` When I attempt to map over the array.

Any direction is greatly appreciated!

My Query:

```js
{
  sanityGallery {
    images {
      asset {
        fluid {
          ...GatsbySanityImageFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This Works:

```js
const images = data.sanityGallery.images
<Img className="grow" fluid={images[0].asset.fluid} />
```

This Does not:

```js
const images = data.sanityGallery.images

<div className="img-container">
  {images.map((image, index) => {
    console.log(image.asset.fluid); // <-- when adding this it logs the info in the screenshot below
    return (
      <div className="box">
        <Img className="grow" fluid={image.asset.fluid} key={index} />
      </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
const images = data.sanityGallery.images

<div className="img-container">
  {images.map((image, index) => {
    console.log(image.asset); // 
    return (
      <div className="box">
        {image.asset && <Img className="grow" fluid={image.asset.srcSet} key={index} />}
      </div>
    )
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Now it gives me error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'srcSet' of null`

Comment: Try: `{image.asset && <Img className="grow" fluid={image.asset.srcSet} key={index} />}` The code won't break but I want to know if it still display the images. Maybe there are one corrupted image breaking the code while the rest (the output you provided) works